# prevent active admin resources from loading on non active_admin pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5

Am using `active_admin` and it works great. Active admin have many dependencies like `jquery-ui, datepicker etc..`

```html
<script src="/assets/active_admin/jquery_ui.self-75a11da44c802486bc6f65640aa48a730f0f684c5c07a42ba3cd1735eb3fb070.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/base.self-ab2cb3098b53fe7d229937d768d701e8f4013f2a5aea7988d8f2149fa40426db.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/batch_actions.self-fbed82dc1e31cf860056cce6c02f5bc5831ad5343d68ac3ab17471c9e05e9195.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/checkbox-toggler.self-ab6f686db7db58fd7f370cd6f7a6d7abe6884b8d2a144f42a744c2276587b457.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/dropdown-menu.self-8ccb356121a1c40094bb429d6cfac85d9c8ad114fb93730892d9df9986730a0a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/flash.self-8f05a5d9328ea28fca100b057787fbfb567986513c5f1735ea48fad8f9571c10.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/has_many.self-ece319debdc01ca5096ae8ac6c130ffc0decab382543b4b94e18591375d3d3bb.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/modal_dialog.self-5dfc6e87bae26cd4a021eb86951d3691ed07e6d2bf242a8eb65dc6965e12096c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/per_page.self-94323c49402595a22bdea01b8dc3f8103e290d300238ebd49efa26d76d7ee117.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/table-checkbox-toggler.self-f5200d732ec9ffd4ee8fd1fe11524ad7b54a67f6c0ef447a29d119ece2dcecdb.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/ext/jquery-ui.self-f96f2ec2a32c4bc4da4292cc74bddeca0bb223d81a421c98c4d613632860945e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/ext/jquery.self-da8dafbbe883092bcae73f35a8caf4ae6170fe7d8130ae7039a233f9b509c757.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/initializers/batch_actions.self-f5c360e8640b40f00640f6e5c7cfe0addeb244ed72e1a9828c52919515d23cf1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/initializers/datepicker.self-f8ac66c85afd35ee1555c09a2418efc7a7930e1f6dd783461379c2bb2184f80e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/initializers/filters.self-9b9312d6bed532db668c5417a009b7fb7caf58f33299783ed02c2c72340a498a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/initializers/tabs.self-65de8b1688d4f8782c04bf07ba6314d3c8b33b9391a482a07214ac4df99dd904.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
```

I am not using these in any other parts in my app. But I can see that it loads regardless of active admin page or not. So is it possible to load those resources only for active admin pages?? (if not possible is it possible to remove active admin from `asset pipeline` so that the dependencies wont load in `other app parts`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you remove 
 `//= require_tree .` from your  `application.js`
and try again ?

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Fivell's answer. I fixed it by [`stub`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/README.md#stub) it right after `required_tree .` to avoid `active_admin.js` being required in `application.js`.

So `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` will become like:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll ...
// ...
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require_tree .
//= stub active_admin
```

In my case (Rails 5.2.3 & ActiveAdmin 2.1.0), changing this doesn't prevent ActiveAdmin from loading `active_admin.css` & `active_admin.js` so the admin page should be fine.

Comment: You also have to put the same line in the /stylesheets/application.scss file to prevent the CSS files from loading. Similarly they will still load just fine on the activeadmin pages.